# Disable Vscode function/class scroll viewer

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I remove this Vscode function/class preview. Seems to have been turned on by default from an update. Apologies if this is a duplicate. This is actually giving me a headache

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had to right click on the section and turn off sticky scroll